# How could i search for missing driver

Tags: drivers, lubuntu

I just installed lubuntu on my laptop but there is no driver for the wifi connection or sound i searched but i still didn't find the way to install them so help me i still a student and i'd like to lean programming

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to find drivers it to first know what you have on your computer. The command for that is.

```
lspci
```

Which in my case returns the following

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0c)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0c)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0c)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0c)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0c)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Once you know what you have you can then google for the driver.

Comment: You can narrow down the search with the pci.id or usb.id. Use lspci -nn or lsusb.